# How to set up a camera recorder to stream on a website?

Tags: linux, streaming, video-streaming

I've to set up a website which will broadcast live video.

A camera recorder will be pluged to a laptop.
The laptop will send the data to a server (same as the http server)

The video will be broadcasted through a flash player.

What are the tools which i could use to do such task ?

The server is a linux platform (debian/ubuntu-server), the laptop is Windows (XP/2000), the camera is unknown.

- will do i need a 'client' on laptop
  to send data to the server ? Which
  one ?
- Will do i need a 'server
  (software)' to stream the video ?
- Which flash player could i use ?
- What should I know before to do that ?

Is there any open source software to do that ? paying ones ? How much ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to set up your own system? If you aren't set on that, there are already some great services out there to stream your own live video from a webcam. Two of the best are:

- [Ustream.tv](http://ustream.tv)
- [Qik](http://qik.com)

These both work by streaming video from a client via a flash applet, and allow you to embed the video to your website.

You could write this all from scratch, but unless you have some sort of business goal that this aligns with, it doesn't make sense to reinvent the wheel, so to speak. The two services I mentioned are both free, with advertising.

Answer (score 3):

[Red5](http://osflash.org/red5) is an open source flash media streaming server that supports several codecs and live stream publishing written in Java.

[VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/) (better known for their specific project VLC - VideoLAN Client) also does live streaming, though I'm not sure to what degree it's considered a good public-facing internet streamer.  I know people use it for that, I just don't know whether you need a simple solutions such as this, or something more.

There are many ways to do this with commercial products, but you'll probably need to narrow your question down so that a specific solution applies, and you don't end up with a list of hundreds of possible solutions you need to sort through.

Answer (score 0):

[ffserver](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html#Stream-examples) can stream directly from a camera. It supports a variety of clients.